# Achieving iOS Music app's UITabBarController with synchronized navigation item between tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want the app that I am developing to have the following functionality, which can be seen in the Apple Music app for iOS:

A `UITabBarController` presents several different `UITableViewController`'s. Selecting any item from these table views will navigate forward to a view controller that plays that audio item. Navigating back to the tab view does not terminate the playing of that item, but leaves a 'Now Playing' forward navigation item on *each* of the different tabs. When that navigation item is selected, the app navigates forward to the *same instance* of the player view regardless of which tab it was selected from.

This can be seen in the screenshots below, where the 'Now Playing' forward navigation item can be seen on multiple tabs.

**Note**: I am doing everything programmatically; no Interface Builder.

[image: Artist's Tab]

[image: Song's Tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you are using a storyboards..

You will hardly be able to achieve a dynamic navigation behavior with storyboards, because they are very static and not very scaleable. -- imho, they suck quite hard, but that's a different story to tell ;) --

If you wanted to achieve this behavior in storyboards, you would have to connect segues in every tab which lead to a 'NowPlayingViewController' -- not scalable + when it comes to presenting the 'nowPlaying BarButtonItem' : pain in the a** with storyboards.

It's much easier in code:

Create a `UIViewController` subclass (in this case probably 'AAPLNowPlayingViewController') as you would normally do. When you absolutes HAVE to build the interface in interfaceBuilder, you can drag a new ViewController in your storyboard and design it there.

Now for the presenting part:

Using storyboards, you would normally start connecting segues from everywhere the 'NowPlayingVC' can be launched -- don't do that, as mentioned above ;) --

Instead, set the barButtonItem ('NowPlaying' button) in every view you want to to be able to launch the nowPlayingVC from.

In the callback (target, selector pair), you'll instantiate your viewController in code and simply call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:nowPlayingViewController animated:YES]`

Instantiating the viewController in code:

Two possibilities here:

1. You created the layout in IB:

   call `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nowPlayingViewController"]`
2. You created the layout in code (much better imho ;)):

simply call `[[NowPlayingViewController alloc] init]`

This will give your app the ability to push the `NowPlayingViewController` from any tab.

Comment: I am doing everything programmatically; no Interface Builder or Storyboards. With regards to your solution: I want each tab's navigation button to be able to navigate to the exact same instance of the player view controller.

Comment: Then you would need to hold on to the playerViewController somewhere in your app (maybe AppDelegate), and push the same instance using the reference you hold on to